# Is there a filter option for Date and time in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that contains that contains both **date and time**. I do not think DateRangeInput filter is working here. I used this filter in R shiny and looks like it is not considering time. I need time as well in my filter. So is there an option other than `DateRangeInput`.  What I meant is DateRangeinput is only for Date I believe.

```
as1
                   da cat
1 2016-06-04 04:05:45   A
2 2016-06-04 04:05:46   B
3 2016-06-04 04:05:45   C
4 2016-06-04 04:05:46   D
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your data isn't even sorted on your time column. So let's fix that.

Second, all R data types can index by position or by logical comparison.  So that is all you need.

Mocked example as you did not provide reproducible code:

```
df <- data.frame(t=ISOdatetime(2019, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0) + 0:9*60, v=LETTERS[1:10])
df    
df[ df$t > ISOdatetime(2019, 1, 1, 10, 2, 0) & df$t < ISOdatetime(2019, 1, 1, 10, 9, 0), ]
```

Output:

```
R> df <- data.frame(t=ISOdatetime(2019, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0) + 0:9*60, v=LETTERS[1:10])
 R> df
                      t v
 1  2019-01-01 10:00:00 A
 2  2019-01-01 10:01:00 B
 3  2019-01-01 10:02:00 C
 4  2019-01-01 10:03:00 D
 5  2019-01-01 10:04:00 E
 6  2019-01-01 10:05:00 F
 7  2019-01-01 10:06:00 G
 8  2019-01-01 10:07:00 H
 9  2019-01-01 10:08:00 I
 10 2019-01-01 10:09:00 J
!R> df[ df$t > ISOdatetime(2019, 1, 1, 10, 2, 0) & df$t < ISOdatetime(2019, 1, 1, 10, 9, 0), ]
                     t v
 4 2019-01-01 10:03:00 D
 5 2019-01-01 10:04:00 E
 6 2019-01-01 10:05:00 F
 7 2019-01-01 10:06:00 G
 8 2019-01-01 10:07:00 H
 9 2019-01-01 10:08:00 I
 R>
```

There are many more way to create Datetime objects.  `as.POSIXct()` is one, I use `anytime::anytime()` a lot to parse (but then I wrote it too...)